# Route Post Returning 403

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a perfectly working web site on Local Machine(Wamp).. But When i uploaded that to Production (Litespeed), i get following issue.

In the production all the pages are working except a page to edit products.
Product edit page loads perfectly but when click on submit button i get 403 exception from server (not laravel). (.htaccess and all sources are same in production and local)

routes.php

```
Route::post('admin/product/{id}/update', 'Admin\ProductController@update');
```

Product Edit

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ url('/admin/product/'. $product->id . '/update') }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"> 

....

</form>
```

ProductController

```
    public function update($id, Request $request)
    {
      return 'hi';
      //My own logic
    }
```

The above code work perfectly in local, but in production i am not getting a page with 'hi' as return. instead i get error 403 from the lite-speed server. which means `public function update` is not getting hit in production.

Not any other post methods are getting hit in server.. all other pages working fine in production

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
```

..

Comment: `.htaccess` usually causes this kind of thing for me. That or relative/absolute path errors.

Comment: Are you using Apache?

Comment: @ScottMcGready, thx i have updated in question with htacess

Comment: @user3158900  Apache is used on my local, but the production is litespeed

Comment: If your production is a shared host, ask them to make sure `.htaccess` configurations are allowed. Some are not.

Comment: @Sam, yes they have allowed .htaccess , otherwiese most other laravel functions will not work,

Comment: Is class `Admin\ProductController` new? If so, you may need to do a `php artisan dump-autoload`.

Comment: @Sam Its not new.. all other non post methods in ProductController are working

Comment: Are you seeing anything in the error log which might give a clue?

Comment: Can you verify that the `csrf_token()` value is successfully rendered by inspecting the source code of your form?

Comment: @user3158900 there is not any specific error on error log (both laravel and apache)...

Comment: @Sam yes... when i inspect the html in browser the token value is filled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to `Mod_Security` module installed in the web server.

This is used to eliminate html tags in the input values (but i wanted to post html tags in the input boxes), so i disabled this module.